# Difference between ActionBarActivity and Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am noob in Android. I just started to use `ActionBarActivity` over `FragmentActivity`. Is there any difference between them ??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`FragmentActivity` is the base class for support based fragments. So you will be using `Fragment` from support library below api level 11 in which case your `Activity` needs to extend `FragmentActivity`.

```
 ↳  android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
                       ↳    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
```

You will use `ActionBarActivity` when you need actionbar below API level 11 by using AppCompat library. In this case your Activity extends `ActionBarActivity`.

As you see `ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`

Comment: How developers were adding action bar + `Fragments` when `ActionBarActivity` was not there ?

Comment: @user3527017 they used a third party library called `ActionBarSherlock`. http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: All backward compatibility classes are in v4 right and what is v7 ?

Comment: @user3527017 why don't you check the docs yourself http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 13):

`ActionBarActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` and adds support for [the `appcompat` action bar backport](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html).