# Can't remove TITLE BAR

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I know this question has been asked for a million times. But none of the answers helped me.
Every time I want to remove the TITLE BAR on MainActivity which extends ActionBarActivity, my application crashes or nothing happens. I have tried everything I could - changed AndroidManifest settings, added:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in any possible way into the `onCreate` method. But nothing seems to work properly. I really hope somebody has an answer because it is getting really frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't extend `ActionBarActivity` which is causing the error, instead use `Activity`.
Unless your min api level is not below 11, it won't change that much ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23090310/5099479) you can read why, but `AppCompatActivity` will probably cause the same error).

If it extends `Activity`, you can use `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)` (min api lvl 15).

Answer (score 0):

I donot have the reputation to comment. So I am posting it as an answer.

Where are you calling the method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

According to my knowledge it must be called before

```
setContentView(R.Layout.yourlayoutname);
```

of your onCreate method.

Can you post the logcat if you are getting the same issue even when you call the methods before the setContentView() method.

You can also use theme from the manifest to remove the title bar from the activity.

Reply for any further assistance.
Hope this helps. Cheers :)

Comment: I did so. I called it before I had set up Content View but it didn't work. Problem is fixed now. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: how did you fix the problem?

Comment: getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

Answer (score 0):

For removing title bar you can use `FullScreenTheme` by adding the code below to styles:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

You can use above theme for a particular activity or for all activity:

**To set this theme for a single activity go to manifest and use:**

```
<activity
    ........
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
```

**To set this theme for all activities go to manifest and use:**

```
<application
        ......
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"/>
```