# Difference between "Java class extends" "AppcompatActivity" vs "Activity" vs "ActionBar" in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, extends, appcompatactivity

Android - I am going to develop an app which API is between API 15 and the latest API.
But I have one question regarding "Java class extends".

What is the difference between:

1. Java class `extends AppcompatActivity`, and
2. Java class `extends Activity`, and
3. Java class `extends ActionBarActivity`.

If someone give a clear definition, I will definitely tick the answer as accepted for my question.

Comment: Depends on the Android API level you want to develop for. For current API levels (> 20) forget about that compat/actionbar stuff and just use an activity.

Comment: extends ActionBar? never read before..!!!

Comment: Thanks. API 15 to newer API .

Comment: ohh it's ActionBarActivity..!!!

Comment: Go through this link. I hope helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23090310/3483989

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- extending `ActionBarActivity` gives you the `ActionBar`s functionality on every API level >= 7
- by extending `Activity` you can avoid adding additional projects/libraries to your project but you'll lack the `ActionBar` on api levels below 11

`ActionBarActivity` is part of the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html). Support libraries are used to deliver newer features on older platforms. For example the `ActionBar` was introduced in API 11 and is part of the `Activity` by default (depending on the theme actually). In contrast there is no `ActionBar` on the older platforms. So the support library adds a child class of Activity (`ActionBarActivity`) that provides the `ActionBar`'s functionality and UI

- The new deprecated version of `ActionBarActivity` (the one extending `AppCompatActivity` class) is a safe to use backward compatibility class. Its deprecation is just a hint for you to use new `AppCompatActivity` directly instead. `AppCompatActivity` is a new, more generic implementation which uses `AppCompatDelegate` class internally.

For instance, you inherit an activity from an external library, which, in turn, does not inherit from `AppCompatActivity` but you want this activity to have tinted **materials widgets** (views). To make it happen you need to create an instance of `AppCompatDelegate` inside your activity, `override` methods of that activity like `addContentView()`, `setContentView()` etc. (see `AppCompatDelegate` javadoc for the full list of methods), and inside those overridden methods forward the calls to inner `AppCompatDelegate` instance. `AppCompatDelegate` will do the rest and your "old-fashion" activity will be "materialized".

Source: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089547/difference-between-extending-activity-and-actionbaractivity/23090310#23090310) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797172/whats-the-enhancement-of-appcompatactivity-over-actionbaractivity).

Answer (score 1):

Extends `AppcompatActivity` is good .`AppcompatActivity` is help us to use new feature in low `api`.