# ActionBar Menu appear when extending FragmentActivity, but not ActonBarActivity. Why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I follow the normal way of creating ActionBar menu for my Activity following the instruction in https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html.

Obviously I extends the ActionBarActivity as per instructed, and import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
public class LaunchActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 
  // All my codes
}
```

However, the Action Bar Menu doesn't appear on the Title Bar, and would only come out as normal option menu when I use the Hardware Menu click.

However if I change to

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
public class LaunchActivity extends FragmentActivity { 
  // All my codes
}
```

Now my Action Bar Menu appear as intended (i.e. appear on the Title Bar). Why was it so?

P/S: My activity instantiate Fragments for it's content view. Thanks!

Comment: If you have `android:minSdkVersion="8"` then  `FragmentActivity`  works. and if you have  `android:minSdkVersion="10"` then `ActionBarActivity` works

Comment: Thanks MD. I thought ActionBarActivity extends from FragmentActivity as per stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045472/difference-between-actionbaractivity-and-fragment-activity. By right, ActionBarActivity should be have better capability of enabling the Action Menu Bar. I got my workaround, just want to have good understanding why such odd behaviour.